# Добрый день! Дискреционный и добровольный. Доказать различия

Tags: этимология, значение-слов

Пишу диссертацию по финансам. Рецензент указал на отсутствие оснований менять сочетание "добровольное" на "дискреционное", хотя вижу между ними различия. Помогите, пожалуйста, найти правильные аргументы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ни «добровольный», ни «самовольный», ни «своеволие», ни «произвол» не передают (в точности) смысла, который европейцы вкладывают в слово «дискреционный» (discretionary).
Это слово означает свободу выбора в строго оговоренных и заранее установленных пределах, в отдельных (separate / discrete) случаях.
Например, на карманные расходы в день получаете определенную сумму денег (discretionary money — свободные деньги) и уже в пределах выделенных д. средств «можете ни в чем себе не отказывать».
Приказ клиента биржевому брокеру купить ценную бумагу, дающий свободу выбора времени и цены сделки - discretionary order. 
За нарушение закона, статьями ГК/УК предусматривается вариативность наказания, т.е. устанавливаются пределы штрафа / срока на усмотрение суда.  Наказание по усмотрению суда - discretionary penalty.
Дискреционные полномочия - discretionary powers - ограниченная определенными пределами власть (своеволие).
https://wooordhunt.ru/word/discretionary

Answer (score 1):

[Дискреционный](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretionary#English:%7E:text=Available%20at%20one%27s%20discretion%3B%20able%20to%20be%20used%20as%20one%20chooses%3B%20left%20to%20or%20regulated%20by%20one%27s%20own%20discretion%20or%20judgment.) - это сделанный на усмотрение того, кто является исполнителем. От [disctretion](https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=discretion#:%7E:text=%22ability%20to%20perceive%20and%20understand%3B%22) - ""ability to perceive and understand," - способность воспринимать, понимать, [видеть различие между понятиями](https://www.etymonline.com/word/discern?ref=etymonline_crossreference#:%7E:text=%22perceive%20or%20recognize%20the%20difference%20or%20distinction%20between%20(two%20or%20more%20things)%3B%22%20also%20%22distinguish%20(an%20object)%20with%20the%20eyes%2C%20see%20distinctly%2C%20behold%3B%22); а "добровольно"(хотя скорее благоразумно), потому что "moral discernment, ability to distinguish right from wrong," - способность отличать правильное от неправильного в рамках морали. Но финансовая сфера не всегда имеет прямое отношение к морали, так что скорее всего кто-то путает *моральную дискрецию* и просто *дискрецию* как таковую.

Воля и добрая воля имеет отношение к конкретному человеку, а дискреционность - это нахождение вне нормативного регламента или при отсутствии регламента как такового. Теоретически, можно переводить дискреционный как добровольный, но далеко не всегда. Я бы переводил **дискреционный** как - **рациональный, разумный/благоразумный(возможно), выбранный/сделанный по собственному усмотрению**. Можно оставить последний вариант и избежать терминологии. Скажем, "все дальнейшие действия **остаются на усмотрение исполнителя** - дельнейшие действия имеют дискреционный характер".

Дискреционный может означать свободный к распоряжению чем-то, ввиду соблюдения должного регламента - [discretionary income](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretionary_income#English) -  "Disposable income minus all payments necessary to meet current bills," - доход, за вычетом всех текущих расходов и оплат по счетам. То есть дискреционный - это свободный ввиду того, что дальнейших инструкций нет или не предусмотрено.

[discretionary fiscal policy](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretionary_fiscal_policy#English:%7E:text=A%20fiscal%20policy%20achieved%20through%20government%20intervention%2C%20as%20opposed%20to%20automatic%20stabilizers.) -  "A fiscal policy achieved through government intervention, as opposed to automatic stabilizers," - налогово-бюджетная политика  проводимая путем непосредственного вмешательства правительства, в противоположность автоматическим(инструментам) стабилизации. Как видно тут слово "добровольный" точно не подойдет, однако, такой подход к управлению в определенных моментах можно считать разумным подходом к управлению.

[Discretionary spending](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/discretionary_spending#English:%7E:text=which%20one%20may%20make%20as%20one%20sees%20fit) - расходы бла-бла, которые "..*one may make* **as one sees fit**." - *кому-то позволенное употребить*(свободен употребить, отсюда видимо и ~доброволен, хотя, тоже неточность, так как не кто-то не "волен", а ему "позволено") **по собственному взгляду на ситуацию**(которая как раз дискреция, не имеющая отношения к доброй или недоброй воле, но к разумному отношению). Разумное отношение предшествует позволению осуществлять добро(а не доброй воле), также как дискреция предшествует позволению делать как кто-то считает нужным. Или по-другому, позволение свободы действий обусловлено способностью агента к дискреции, а вовсе не разрешение делать, что хочется, своевольничать и даже добровольность. И есть еще момент fit - ситуация/ситуативный подход к, определен рамками закона, или правилами, или "свободным" выбором из ограниченного числа вариантов.

Так что я не соглашусь, что **дискреционный** хоть где-то можно заменить на **добровольный**, или наоборот. Но кто прав, сложно сказать, так как текста от вас нет.

Ну и если уже совсем уходить в корень, то дис-**крет**ный родственное с **крит**ика, **крит**ерий и **кри**зис, но в латыни значит **судить** не абы как, а в **соответствии с законами/правом** - [**judgement/crime**](https://www.etymonline.com/word/*krei-?ref=etymonline_crossreference#:%7E:text=Latin%20cribrum%20%22sieve%2C%22%20crimen%20%22judgment%2C%20crime%2C%22), в отличие от греческого первоисточника [**krinein**](https://brewminate.com/krinein-defining-the-cult-hero/#:%7E:text=the%20%E2%80%9Cmiddle%20voice%E2%80%9D%20for%20which%20is%C2%A0krinesthai%2C%20and%20the%20meaning%20of%20which%20is%20%E2%80%98judge%2C%20distinguish%2C%20make%20distinctions%E2%80%99.).

Comment: Я раньше не задумывалась над этим словом, а теперь поняла, что оно значит. Но главное — в ответе есть ответ на заданный вопрос, причем вполне ясный (можно или нельзя менять слова). Различия указаны,вывод сделан.

Comment: @Sharon что интересно, что никакие "новые" и внезапное значения не появляются, все очень логично, стоит лишь провести черту между латинской и греческой культурами, ну и нашей русской, которая во многом от греческой и восточной, а не правовой латинской - от римского права. Латинские же слова выглядят как термины, подчиненные иной системе "критериев" и оценок.

Comment: Конечно, вы правы.  Мне для понимания практически любого слова нужно знать его корень (латинский, греческий, индоевропейский и т.д.). Но я не уверена, что так считают другие пользователи языка. И уж тем более различают латинскую и греческую культуры, как вы.